# ASP.NET GridView set values using JavaScript Fucntion

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

In the ItemTemplate of TemplateField of the GridView itis posible to set value using functions from CodeBehind. In the example I call getImgUrl and getNavUrl to set Image and Navigate URLs. I would like to know the syntax required to call a JavaScript function instead of a code behind function. That is, the combination of brackets, percent signs, hashtags, etc.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hHoldEm" Target="_parent" runat="server" Font-Underline="false" ImageUrl='<%# getImgUrl(Eval("CER_ACTIVE"))%>' ToolTip="Hold/UnHold..." ImageWidth="20" NavigateUrl='<%# getNavUrl(Eval("CER_ACTIVE"), Eval("CER_NO"))%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a function in code behind with a `HyperLink` by adding a `OnClick` event as you would a `Button`.

But you can call javascript function in an anchor like this

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction()">Click for JavaScript</a>
```

So to do the same in the GridView you can do this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hHoldEm" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:" + getNavUrl(Eval("CER_ACTIVE"), Eval("CER_NO")) %>' />
```

or

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hHoldEm" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:myFunction(&#39;" + Eval("CER_ACTIVE") + "&#39;, &#39;" + Eval("CER_NO") + "&#39;)" %>' />
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I would have been nice, then in the Gridview it would be simple to set the PageSize based on browser height like this "PageSize='<%# "javascript:setPageSize()" %>'". Unfortunately not.